# Can't render {this.state.city}

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm creating a weather app in React using OpenWeatherMap API. There are input form and a button, and I'm expecting to see city name when I click the botton. I received data from the API when I do so, but can't render it on a screen while I can log it in a console.

For this, I'm using three separated files. App.js, Form.js for submitting terms, and weather.js for API configuration.

I'm guessing that I need to map the received data but not yet successful.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        city: null,
    }

    getWeather = async city => {
        const response = await weather.get('/forecast', {
            params: {
                q: city
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            city: response.name,
        })
        console.log(city); <--- This works
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
                <Form loadWeather={this.getWeather} />            
                <p>{this.state.city}</p> <--- This doesn't work                    
            </div>
        );        
    }
}
```

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    state = { term: '' };

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.loadWeather(this.state.term);
        this.refs.textInput.value = '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <input 
                    ref="textInput"
                    type="text" 
                    value={this.state.term} 
                    onChange={event => this.setState({term: event.target.value})}
                     />
                    <button>Get Weather</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Form;
```

I'm going to pass the {this.state.name} as a prop to a child component, but so far the received data doesn't even appear on that component ifself.

Comment: from where you are invoking the getWeather method?

Comment: I made a separate js file. I put API key and base URL in it, and they're working fine.

Comment: So you are calling the function from a separate file?. i'm not quite getting what you are saying.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the "getWeather" function from a separate file so that I can reuse it later on when I want to make another API application. I put `import weather from '../apis/weather';` on the very top of App.js

Comment: Do you pass `getWeather` to some child component of `App` and call it from there?

Comment: >Maaz Syed Adeeb Yes, exactly.

Comment: in `getWeather` you're console logging the passed in param, `city`. In the component you're trying to render `this.state.city` which you're setting to the `name` attribute of the result object. try console logging `response.name`, my guess is it's null. If so, log `response` and inspect it to see what you actually get back from the API.

Comment: ^ in addition to that, since you tagged `axios`, my guess is you need `response.data.name` :)

Comment: >Maaz Syed Adeeb I'm so sorry I thought it was 'weather' not 'getWeather'... sorry for the confusion... :(
I call getWeather from 'Form.js'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting state's `city` to `response.name`. You tagged the question as axios, so I'm assuming you're using axios for the ajax. If so, you'll want to get the data from the response back from `response.data.name`, not `response.name`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed to `city: response.data.city.name,` and it finally worked!! This is my first API application and I didn't know how to dig in response object. Can't appreciate enough!

Answer (score 5):

"this.setState"  is a function, should be called like this.

```
this.setState({
    city: response.name,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the city details from the initial render try calling/invoking the `getWeather()` method in `componentDidMount()` life cycle. The way you are using `setState()` is also wrong. it should be something like this as mentioned below. The same lifecyle could be used to get the data even though you have used a separate file to invoke the method

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        city: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWeather("city");
    }

    getWeather = async city => {
        const response = await weather.get("/forecast", {
            params: {
                q: city
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            city: response.name
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.city}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I think I was missing some details. I tried the code above but couldn't get expecting result. Maybe there's a problem in the other component. What I was trying to do right now is, I want to render a city name when I input a value and click a button. I fixed my code.